# Infopath cannot submit form to Sharepoint List

Tags: submit, warnings, sharepoint-2013, infopath, sharepoint-list

I am trying to create an Infopath form to submit and change data in a Sharepoint Server List.  If I have the form submit to a Sharepoint Server Form Library, it works perfectly fine.  I followed the step-by-step instructions to submit a form to a list at the following: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/03/26/submitting-to-a-sharepoint-list.aspx

That guide's results is exactly what I would need.  The list comes out great in the Infopath form, however, when I try to test it and submit the form, I get an error.  If I preview and try to fill out the form from within Infopath (after publishing it), I log in as an administrator account that has Full Control permissions.  When I click the Submit button, the changes are reverted back to the way it was before!  If I click Submit in the Preview's Home tab, the form just closes and I'm not able to see any changes within the database list.

However, if I try submitting from a browser, I would get a warning error like below (after showing error details):

**Warning**

**The form cannot be submitted because of an error.**

**Click OK to resume filling out the form.  You may want to check your form data for errors.**

**An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.**

**An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.**

**Log ID: 5567**

**Correlation ID:635e5d9c-20f5-10a9-d022-b92274809ed0**

Why would the submitting work for Sharepoint form libraries but not for Sharepoint Lists?  I'm quite confused as this is a complicated process that should have been kept simple for users.

Please help.  Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

1. What versions of infopath and SharePoint are you using?
2. Have you tried testing your form to make sure it's compatible with a browser? You can do this [within infopath.][1]
3. Correlation ID's are GUIDs that point to an error log in your SharePoint environment, it should give a more detailed description of your error.

   http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-find-error-messages-with-a-correlation-id-token-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: Dear Jimmy,

Thank you for your reply.  

1. I am using 2013 for both.

2. Yes, it works on the browser.  If it submits to a form library, no problem.  If it submits to a list, that's where the error comes up.

3. I tried to view the Correlation ID with that guide you provided.  When I input that command into the Sharepoint 2013 Management Shell, it just stops there and doesn't show anything.  I even tried the one that exports a log file to the C: drive, still doesn't work.  It looks as if it is loading something, but nothing comes up.

Thanks for your assistance!
Jason

Comment: Hi Jimmy,

After a while, a file did actually get created!  Can I email you that log file?  It is much too long for placing into a Comment box.  I'm unsure of how to troubleshoot the issue.

Thanks for the assistance.
Jason